# limit point of open sets

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

Is every point $x \in U$ in an open set $U \subset X$of a normed space $(X,||\cdot||)$ a limit point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because  for $x \neq 0$ we have $x =\lim (1+\frac 1 n) x$. For $x=0$ take any non-zero vector $y$ in $U$ and write $x$ as the limit of $\frac 1 n y$.

Comment: ah, nice way to show this :)